# NSInternalInconsistencyException UISelectionFeedbackGenerator crashlog explaining

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics

> Terminating app due to an uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Exception raised while auto-deactivating  for style 2: force deactivating  with style TurnOn which is not active (activationCount = -1) configuration: <_UISelectionFeedbackGeneratorConfiguration: 0x1cc10a200: isEnabled=1, activationStyle=2, requiredSupportLevel=0> activationCount: -1, styleActivationCount: -1 engines: {( <_UIFeedbackHapticOnlyEngine: 0x1c80dac50: state=4, numberOfClients=7, prewarmCount=0, _isSuspended=0> )}'

What is this issue? I can't reproduce it with Simulator, but I see some live users have experience with this issue on different pages in the app. However, I don't have any mentions of using `UISelectionFeedbackGenerator` in the code.

Most crashes happens after user clicks "Done" `button`, which is located on `UIToolbar` that hides `UIPickerView`. But it doesn't crash right after that action, but after 4-5 seconds.

Here is `.h` and `.m` files of Picker implementation. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fb0aad8a8fb1abf8f292882bd8fa49fe and https://gist.github.com/anonymous/170ba5346b68a15a5b6e75c04af8b159

**Can anyone explain what could cause the issue?**

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in your question and not just links that are pointing to your code.

Comment: it doesn't crash at specific line, so I can't point to an exact part of code. But it crashes after using that `UIPickerView`. That's all I have in crashlogs from Appsee...